# PHP array size value error

Tags: php, arrays, file, upload, size

This is my code:

```
 if(isset($_FILES['productimage']['name'])!='') 
    {
     echo $arraysize=sizeof($_FILES['productimage']['name']);
   for($i=0;$i<$arraysize;$i++)
    {
      .....
    }
```

Here, I can't upload any image, but it shows size is 1.

So is it creating an empty file?

What is the exact problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: what you tying to do?

Comment: You should check for `$_FILES['productimage']['error']` and that value must be `0`. Btw, what's the form you're submitting?

Comment: what do you want to do with your product name?

Comment: Why don't you try `if (file_exists ( $_FILES ['productimage'] ['tmp_name'] )) {  // yes file is uploaded}`

Comment: @Log1c At the very least that should be `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productimage']['tmp_name'])`.

Comment: Thanks btw, but for me `file_exists` works every time :)

Comment: did you print the $_FILES ? Did you check it first is it empty or not?

Answer (score 1):

When a form containing `<input type=file>` is submitted, PHP will populate the `$_FILES` array, even if the file was not uploaded.

This means that the array keys will be set (`isset` will return true) but they will (or will not) contain meaningful values. Best way to check if a file was actually uploaded is [to check the error code associated with the file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

```
if (isset($_FILES["productimage"]) && $_FILES["productimage"]["error"] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // handle uploaded file
}
```

In the above example `isset($_FILES["productimage"])` is added to ensure that the array key is set; whether or not the file was uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug this way to to figure out where's the problem:

```
if ($_FILES["productimage"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["productimage"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["productimage"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["productimage"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["productimage"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["productimage"]["tmp_name"];
}
```